# Monitoring solution wihtout client-install

Tags: linux, monitoring

I already wasted days to look for a very minimalist (*cpu/ram/ping/ssh/disks*) monitoring tools that discover hosts by itself instead of installing a client application on each host. (*I can accept giving a temporary account with ssh-key*) but not any local binaries installation. 
(*because the solution have to be movable from a LAN to another or another or another  for few days only*)

I did not find any? Do you know such product?

Currently I use a boring MySQL/Nagios couple of docker containers but this solution is very bad because it doesn't do discovering (*so I can only monitor hosts that client knows/remember existence*) & I lose half a day to one day to setup it specially for the concerned LAN...

Do you know a solution corresponding to my needs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you do not use nagios properly. In nagios you define hosts, host groups, services per host group. And you need to set/change host names only and (if needed) reallocate them over host groups.

Other possible solution is to use SNMP. Per host you define snmp agent with probes for the services you need. And one sample script can "browse" the network for available snmp agent and add it in to monitoring solution.

Comment: So you mean I would run a script working around snmp to generate the "new" LAN *.cfg file & startup nagios each time I connect the laptop to a new LAN ? but snmp can be unavailable  so it its not a full range solution... but it can help :)

Comment: @francoisP, right. But w/o any way to access the monitored machine or get (via snmp or native client) the info you want you can't monitor the network. As you mention ssh key you can use it to collect info using this way. You do not need to be root to collect some of the info. And having SNMP agent installed on monitored machines do not seems unreasonable

Comment: OK so I guess it is quite a good direction to work around it. Thanks

Comment: Many Unix/Linux already have `SNMP` (Standard Network Monitoring Protocol` already installed. Install `snmp-tools` (package name may vary) locally, and read `man snmpget snmpwalk`.

Answer (score 0):

[DBMarlin](https://www.dbmarlin.com/) will do what you want with just ssh and mysql login details, but it won't do auto-discovery - you will have to tell it what hosts to monitor and what key/username/password to use on each. It is one of the few options that doesn't require you to install a client-side package and still lets you get some OS level metrics (e.g. CPU usage).